# Customising Wordpress "more" tag to display an except rather than everything prior to that point

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment I am using the `more` tag in wordpress to cut of my posts after about one paragraph on my home page, I am wanting to be able to have more control over what is displayed as the excerpt but selecting a start and an end point somehow. I am aware that this is not standard functionality of the more feature but is there a way to customise the `more` tage or is there an excerpt feature that can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which version wordpress you are on, but you might be looking for the Excerpt functionality:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt

When you are editing a post if you don't see the "Excerpt," box, click the "Screen Options," box on the top of the screen. For 3.4.8 the screen options box is in the top right of the screen. You can click a checkbox that will display the excerpt box and write your excerpt in there. Then use:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

When you are theming. Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-post-excerpts-in-wordpress-themes/